# After grouping, how can I get the values of all other nodes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, split, group

With the attached XML, I want to split the `<rf>` on the basis of `<key>CC</key>` and `<key>Att</key>` which falls under `<rec>`. I am able to achieve that through my XSLT. Unfortunately I am not able to get all other template values since the path is not reversely tracked.

My XML is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rfs>
  <rf id="cc_1_at_2_fid_3">
        <addData>
            <entry>
                <key>CC</key>
                <value>ASARL</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>Att</key>
                <value>BAR, GrÃ©gory  Louis Joseph </value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>Own</key>
                <value>ASARL</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>Own</key>
                <value>GNV</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>App</key>
                <value>GNV</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>App</key>
                <value>ASARL</value>
            </entry>
        </addData>
        <CC>cc_1_at_2</CC>
        <name>XYZ</name>
        <ref>AV-25</ref>
        <recs>
            <rec id="cc_1_at_2_204122094">
                <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Grant</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Div</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
                <ref>AV-25-1</ref>
                <att>BARJoseph </att>
                <agent>CP</agent>
            </rec>
            <rec id="cc_1_at_2_204121989">
                <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Grant</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
                <ref>AB-25-2</ref>
                <owner>ANV</owner>
               </rec>
            <rec id="cc_1_at_2_203449195">
                <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Pappl</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
                <ref>AB-25-3</ref>
                <att>BAoseph </att>
            </rec>
            <rec id="cc_1_at_2_204123928">
                <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Grant</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
               <ref>AB-25-4</ref>
                 <att>BAJoseph </att>
            </rec>
            <rec id="cc_1_at_2_204124349">
                <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Abandoned</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
                <ref>AB-252-5</ref>
               <att>BARJoseph </att>
            </rec>
        </recs>
        <col>false</col>
        <costMod>1.0</costMod>
    </rf>
 </rfs>
```

The XSLT I have written to split and group the `<rf>` is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gala="http://www.tridan.it/gala" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="APOS" select='"&apos;"'/>
    
<xsl:function name="gala:formatId">
    <xsl:param name="unformattedId"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($unformattedId, concat(' &amp;/()][*,’|\',$APOS), '_')"/>
</xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="/rfs" exclude-result-prefixes="gala">  
<xsl:copy>
  
<xsl:variable name="famId">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(rf/@id,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each-group select="rf/recs/rec/addData/entry[key='CC']" group-by="value">
 <xsl:variable name="ccName11" select="current-group()[1]/value"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/../entry[key='Att']" group-by="value">
        <xsl:variable name="ccName22" select="current-group()[1]/value"/>

        <xsl:variable name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="gala:formatId(concat($ccName11,'_',$ccName22))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
    
        <xsl:variable name="famIdfinal">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($id,$famId)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
    
      <rf id="{$famIdfinal}">

    <CC>
            <xsl:value-of select="$id"></xsl:value-of>
        </CC>
    
      </rf>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output XML is shown below which is splitting the `<rf>` into two `<rf>` depending on  `<key>CC</key>` and `<key>Att</key>` under each `<rec>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rfs>
    <rf id="GNV_BJoseph_fid_3">
        <CC>GNV_BJoseph_</CC>
    </rf>
    <rf id="ASARL_BJoseph_fid_3">
        <CC>ASARL_BJoseph_</CC>
    </rf>
</rfs>
```

What I am not able to achieve is to retrieve all other values of every node. So that my final XML Output should look like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rfs>
    <rf id="GNV_BJoseph_fid_3">
      <addData>
            <entry>
                <key>CC</key>
                <value>ASARL</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>Att</key>
                <value>BAR, GrÃ©gory  Louis Joseph </value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>Own</key>
                <value>ASARL</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>Own</key>
                <value>GNV</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>App</key>
                <value>GNV</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>App</key>
                <value>ASARL</value>
            </entry>
        </addData>
         <CC>GNV_BJoseph_</CC>
        <name>XYZ</name>
        <ref>AV-25</ref>
        <recs>
            <rec id ="GNV_BJoseph_fid_3_204122094">
            <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Grant</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Div</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
            <ref>AB-25-1</ref>
            <att>BARJoseph </att>
            <agent>CP</agent>           
            </rec>
            <rec id ="GNV_BJoseph_fid_3_203449195">
      <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Pappl</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
                <ref>AB-25-3</ref>
                <att>BAoseph </att>
        </rec>
            <rec id ="GNV_BJoseph_fid_3_204123928">
            <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Grant</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
               <ref>AB-25-4</ref>
                 <att>BAJoseph </att>
        </rec>
        </recs>
    </rf>
    <rf id="ASARL_BJoseph_fid_3">
         <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Abandoned</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
        <CC>ASARL_BJoseph_</CC>
        <name>XYZ</name>
        <ref>AV-25</ref>
        <recs>
            <rec id ="ASARL_BJoseph_fid_3_204121989">
              <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Grant</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
                <ref>AB-25-2</ref>
                <owner>ANV</owner>
          </rec>
            <rec id ="ASARL_BJoseph_fid_3_204124349">
                 <addData>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CSta</key>
                        <value>Abandoned</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>CC</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Att</key>
                        <value>BJoseph </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Own</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>GNV</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>App</key>
                        <value>ASARL</value>
                    </entry>
                </addData>
                <ref>AB-252-5</ref>
               <att>BARJoseph </att>
        </rec>
        </recs>
    </rf>
</rfs>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am getting lost in all the data in the samples, I understand the grouping keys you want but I don't see exactly which elements belong into each result `rf` group? Can you explain that with some sentences and/or cut the samples data so that it is easier to identify the values in the result you have shown? Is each `rf` result containing a copy of all source `rf` children minus the `CC` that gets a new value? Or have more elements to be changed or eleminated?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
  <xsl:template match="rfs">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="rf/recs/rec/addData" composite="true" group-by="entry[key = ('CC', 'Att')]/value">
        <rf id="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::rf/*"/>
        </rf>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="CC">
    <xsl:copy>{current-grouping-key()}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

is closer to what you want (I have used XSLT 3 with a composite grouping key and a text value template for compactness but of course you can use nested for-each-group elements or a concatenated grouping key if you are restricted to XSLT 2, also use `xsl:value-of` instead of the text value template to populate the `CC` element.

After your comment I think the complete solution is more complex, you want to filter out elements, I think you can do that with e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="rfs">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="rf/recs/rec/addData" composite="true" group-by="entry[key = ('CC', 'Att')]/value">
        <rf id="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::rf/*" mode="subtree"/>
        </rf>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="subtree" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="rec" mode="subtree">
    <xsl:if test=". intersect current-group()/..">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()" mode="#current"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="CC" mode="subtree">
    <xsl:copy>{current-grouping-key()}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen  , with your input, I was able to do the grouping using nested for-each-group since I am using XSLT 2. I am also able to retrieve other values. What I am now unable to do is separating out the `<rec>` into proper grouping. I have 5 `<rec>` with different ids. They will have to be moved into 2 groups that I have created after comparing `<CC>` value with `<addData/enrty/key='CC'>` and `<addData/entry/key='Att'>`

Comment: @user13583928, see whether the edit helps.

Comment: Thanks @Martin.That was really helpful and new learning!
One thing I also wanted to update the <rec id =""> with <CC> value 
E.g I want for the first <rf>
<rec id = GNV BJoseph_204122094>
<rec id = GNV BJoseph_203449195>
<rec id = GNV BJoseph_204123928>


And similarly the below for 2nd <rf>
<rec id = ASARL BJoseph_204121989>
<rec id = ASARL BJoseph_204124349>

Comment: @user13583928, add templates e.g. `<xsl:template match="rec/@id" mode="subtree"><xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="current-grouping-key()"/></xsl:template>` that fill in the values you want/need.

Comment: Thanks @Martin , that worked, but I also wanted to include the number to make each `<rec id>` unique
Like 
<rec id = GNV BJoseph_204122094> 
<rec id = GNV BJoseph_203449195> 
<rec id = GNV BJoseph_204123928>
 
As of now I am getting 
<rec id = GNV BJoseph> 
<rec id = GNV BJoseph> 
<rec id = GNV BJoseph>
which is not making `<rec id>` unique. Can you please suggest how to achieve that.That would be really appreciable.

Comment: @user13583928, try on your own, you will know better than I which data from your input contains the value(s) you want to output so e.g. `select="current-grouping-key() || '_' || generate-id()"` would use a generated id, if the data is from your input make sure you select the right element or attribute.

Comment: I tried with generate-id, but while concatenating, it gives the below error. How to resolve this. 
XPTY0004: The parameter value ('2' item(s)) at position '1' of the 'concat' function has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:anyAtomicType ('zero or one')

  <xsl:template match="rec/@id" mode="subtree">
   <xsl:variable name="id1" select="current-grouping-key()" />
   <xsl:variable name="id2" select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(.,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$id1||$id2"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:template>